# Request.cookies from external class

Tags: asp.net, cookies

For my webpages, I decided to create a reusable, external (that is, the code is a separate class outside of the page's own classes), class to deal with managing cookies in a certain fashion.

So in my class constructor, I did something like this:

```
private property cookiepageas Page
Public Sub New(whatpage as Page)
  cookiepage= whatpage
End Sub
```

This allows me to pass the page context to my external class.
This way, I can get intellisense to allow me to do this:
    private property cookie as httpcookie
    cookie = cookiepage.Request.Cookies.Get(cookiename)    'get the current cookie

That compiles.  The problem is that when I run it in the browser, I get this error:

> Request is not available in this context

How, then, can I request the cookie from my external class?
*(you can post vb or c# - I like both)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, instead of passing the Page, [I did this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373771/asp-net-is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-cookie-from-a-static-class?rq=1):

```
cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(cookiename)
```